# SharePoint 2013 extranet - acces outside the internal network

Tags: extranet

I want to know how I can setup a extranet for my users.

They have to be able to connect with SharePoint without using VPN.

Please give me the steps?

Thank you!

Comment: You 'll need to clarify to have better answers :
How your external users will authenticate themselves,     Where are your SharePoint Server(s), What is the expected security level, Do you need communication or not with internal servers, ... 

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can expose your SharePoint WFE on your DMZ and rely on Form Based Authentication (or any other claim based authentication provider) (or even assume they have an account in your AD and connect through NTLM although you might have issue with proxies) but that's risky (but working)

If you have ForeFront / ISA / F5 / ... you can expose some of your SharePoint applications / site to external users while keeping the servers inside your LAN with high security controls.

It could be as simple as this

[image]

You can refer from this official poster showing different topologies that can be put in place : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24079

The common ones are

- Edge firewall topology (as displayed above)
- Back-to-back perimeter topology
- Split back-to-back topology

A nice overview (for previous edition of SharePoint but still valid for SP2013) can be found here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287908%28v=office.12%29.aspx

You 'll need to clarify :

- How your external users will authenticate themselves
- Where are your SharePoint Server(s)
- What is the expected security level
- Do you need communication or not with internal servers (assuming it's put on your DMZ, ...)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify Benny's response above, I wrote the "Configuring FBA in SharePoint 2013" blog he references and it covers an "out of the box" FBA scenario...ExCM is not used in the blog post.  It simply covers a straightforward FBA configuration using the SQL membership provider.  I did use a custom import/export utility we wrote to add users, but other than that it is very "vanilla" in nature.

SharePoint Solutions will be releasing a 2013 version of ExCM, but my main goal with the post was to look at how FBA configuration differed between 2010 and 2013.

Glad to hear that it's been helpful so far!

Matthew McBride

Answer (score 1):

There are a few guides that you can use. One is [Configuring Forms Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.se/2012/08/configuring-forms-based-authentication.html) which uses the addon Extranet Collaboration Manager (ExCM). This guide uses 20+ screenshots which eventually leads you to the fun part of sharing with an external user:

[image]